# Docker compose with Postresql runs into a zero-length delimited identifier

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to run postresql with docker compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

When I then try to start it with `docker compose up` I get the following error:

```
db-1        | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... 2022-09-19 12:45:21.913 UTC [30] FATAL:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """" at character 12
db-1        | 2022-09-19 12:45:21.913 UTC [30] STATEMENT:  ALTER USER ""test"" WITH PASSWORD E'"test"';
db-1        |   
db-1        | child process exited with exit code 1
```

I have experimented with single quotes, double quotes, no quotes for the environment variables, but the issue persists. My understanding is that nothing that isn't in the `docker-compose.yml` can be affecting the database. There is no postgres running locally when I try to start this. What is causing the issue?

Edit: Docker compose version is

```
➜  ~ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.10.2
```

Edit: Added the output of a non-printable character checker

[image: Output]

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem; you `docker-compose.yml` syntax looks just fine, and it comes up without an error on my system. What version of `docker-compose` are you running (maybe add the output of `docker-compose version` to your question)?

Comment: Added docker compose version - v2.10.2

Comment: Your compose file works fine locally with the same version of `docker compose`. I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: I also cannot see any reason why it shouldn't work either, but restarting pretty much everything, running postgres locally and stopping it again didn't help, the issue persists.

Comment: The error message suggests you have too many quotes around some of the identifiers sent to the database during its initialization.  But it is not clear why that should be the case.  Double check that your docker-compose actually is exactly what you presented here.  Look for things like invisible characters, inspect it with a different editor that might see things your current one does not, dump it through `od`, etc.

Comment: I've added the yml with all invisible characters. That does not seem to be the problem. I've now been able to reproduce it on another laptop. I start up the laptop, terminate postgres that was using the port, run `docker compose up` - same error.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your specific environment?  What OS (and version) are you running? Does the laptop on which you were able to reproduce the error have the same configuration? Update the question rather than answering in comments -- that way people will see the information.

Comment: In the end the issue just went away by itself after a few restarts and I have no idea what had been causing it.